# History/Reputation Bug

Tags: bug

I found some sort of cache bug when browsing previous answers. If I browse to this [previous answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/156121/getting-xdebug-to-work-with-dev-desktop/156209#156209) then hit back in my browser. It reports my reputation & visited history as if it was 6 days older than it is.

[image]

When I browse anonymously under the same browser (Chrome) it doesn't appear.